# Automatically toggle RTS line (Delphi Prism SerialPort)

Tags: serial-port, toggle, delphi-prism-2010

I am using SerialPort under Delphi Prism. I am able to send bytes out to the serialport, but I can't receive data from outside, because the SerialPort Request to Send (RTS) line is always high or up. So, what setting do you set to automatically toggle the RTS line?

Here are the serialport properties I set:

```
SerialPort1 := new System.Io.Ports.SerialPort();
SerialPort1.BaudRate:=19200;
SerialPort1.DataBits:=8;
SerialPort1.DtrEnable:=true;
SerialPort1.Parity:=System.IO.Ports.Parity.Even;
SerialPort1.PortName:='COM1';//'/dev/ttyS0';
SerialPort1.ReadBufferSize:=3000;
SerialPort1.ReadTimeout:=1000;
SerialPort1.ReceivedBytesThreshold:=1;
SerialPort1.RtsEnable:=true;
SerialPort1.StopBits:=System.IO.Ports.StopBits.One;
SerialPort1.WriteTimeout:=1000;
SerialPort1.DataReceived += new System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(@MySerialData);
SerialPort1.Open;
```

I do have DTR set. Request to Send line is how you control when to read and write data to the serial. RTS is high then you can only write and if RTS is low you can only read. We have checked the communication line on the oscilloscope and the RTS line is always high, which means our program can only send bytes but not able to read any bytes or data from outside. That is the main reason why the DataReceived Event never gets to execute, because it never sees any incoming bytes or data.

So, after looking at my serial port setting, can you tell me what I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RTS is output so it doesn't have anything to do with receiving. Try turning on DTR and/or CTS.

EDIT:

Try removing the RTS enabled line and adding handshaking for RTS/CTS (not sure what exactly it is in Delphi). I know what the pins are for and what they are supposed to do. Do you have the pinouts showing how this is wired. I assume 2 & 3 are crossed, DTR to DSR both directions, RTS to CTS both directions.

Comment: For handshake, I only have 4 different built-in options to choose from - None, RequestToSend, RequestToSendXonXoff and XonXoff. But if I choose anyone of them other than the None for handshake option, serialport.Write routine times out all the time no matter what I set the writeTimeout property to. So, I manually set and reset RTS right before and after write procedure. It seems to work, but only that I have to have a NoOp loop right before setting RTS to low to get the precise timing for reading data. Or all the incoming or response bytes are lost.

Comment: Right now, my DataReceived Event is firing because it sees incoming bytes.

Comment: @digit  I don't know Delphi, but in .Net RequestToSend handshaking seems to raise RTS automatically when it has data to send.  Sorry if I confused you.  If you are doing this manually, raise  RTS, wait for CTS, then send.